# update ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, updates

when I try to update my 18.04 with `sudo apt update` command it fails. I have the following results and I don't know what's the problem.

```
    Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
Reading package lists... Done                                                  
E: Release file for http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 5h 36min 49s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
E: Release file for http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 6h 26min 40s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
```

Comment: Your system clock is wrong, in the 'future' too far to recognize the archives as legit.  The 5.5/6.5hrs is [near] your timezone difference from UST time?

Answer (score 2):

You need to correct system clock according to your timezone.

Go to *Settings* in the Ubuntu Dash. Click the *Details* tab and then select the *Date & Time* option.

Make sure your *Automatic Date & Time* button are turned on. This will enable you to automatically fetch the current date and time from the internet server.